# when I added spring-security (basic Auth) then the getMpping works but the postMaping show 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
@Autowired
UserService userService;

@PostMapping("/adduser")
public String addUser(@RequestBody Users user){

    return userService.addUser(user);

}

@PutMapping("/updateuser/{id}")
public Users update(@PathVariable Long id,@RequestBody Users 
user){
    return userService.update(id,user);
}

//GET-USER
@GetMapping("/user/{id}")
public Users findUser(@PathVariable Long id){
    return userService.findUserById(id);

}
@DeleteMapping("/deleteuser/{id}")
public String delete(@PathVariable Long id){
    return userService.delete(id);
}

@GetMapping("/getuser")
public List<Users> findUser(){
    List<Users> usersList = userService.findAll();
    Collections.sort(usersList);
    return usersList;
}
```

}

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:userandroles
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

My post and get mapping working perfectly fine but when I added security (basic Auth) then the getMpping worked but the postMaping showed`enter code here` 403 Forbidden

My get and post Mapping works fine after adding spring-security

Comment: You need a CSRF token, without it POST/PUT/DELETE will be blocked. Unless you include it or disable CSRF tokens (enabled by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue, you have a few options:
1: Include CSRF token in your requests You can include the CSRF token in your POST, PUT, and DELETE requests as a request parameter or a header. Here's an example of how to include it as a header:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/adduser").permitAll() // Allow unauthenticated access to POST /adduser
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

2: Disable CSRF protection (not recommended)
If you're working on a stateless RESTful API or if you have other means of protecting against CSRF attacks, you can choose to disable CSRF protection altogether. However, this approach is not recommended unless you have alternative security measures in place. Here's an example of how to disable CSRF protection:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/adduser").permitAll() // Allow unauthenticated access to POST /adduser
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use the first solution error not resolved but I tried second and it worked

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).